# Getting unexpected symbol in span title attribute

Tags: html, tooltip, title

I'm displaying tooltip title upon hovering on something. But I'm getting a unexpected symbol in my tooltip title. The title is constructed from a string builder. So I'm getting the below symbol on end of each line in my title. How can I resolve this.

[image]

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Please, show us the code and provide more details